# Динамический запрос MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно передать в функцию mySql и выполнить содержимое функции:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`u0681910`@`%` FUNCTION `new_function`(`in_Nom_tec` INT ,`in_UID` char(150),`in_date` datetime, `in_table` char(30)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

insert into in_table (Nom_tec, UID, Date_create) values (in_Nom_tec, in_UID, in_date); 

RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

При обращении к функции, ругается что не найдена таблица.. 
Как можно изменить эту функцию?

Comment: Только динамическим SQL. [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: И не надо плодить [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961076/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-mysql) своего вопроса.

Comment: @Akina можете подсказать структуру этого запроса? Никак не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=`u0681910`@`%` 
FUNCTION `new_function`(`in_Nom_tec` INT ,
                        `in_UID` char(150),
                        `in_date` datetime, 
                        `in_table` char(30)) 
RETURNS int(11)
NOT DETERMINISTIC    -- обязательно!
MODIFIES SQL DATA    -- весьма желательно
SQL SECURITY DEFINER -- иначе нахрена DEFINER?
BEGIN
    SET @sql := CONCAT('insert into ', in_table, ' (Nom_tec, UID, Date_create) values (?, ?, ?)');
    SET @in_Nom_tec := in_Nom_tec;
    SET @in_UID := in_UID;
    SET @in_date := in_date;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @in_Nom_tec, @in_UID, @in_date;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Comment: в строке EXECUTE stmt USING Nom_tec, UID, Date_create; ругается на "Nom_tec" - is not valid at this position, expecting: "@"

Comment: Ну скопируйте значения из переменных-параметров в UDV. Типа `SET @Nom_tec:=Nom_tec;`. Какие сложности-то?

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что так нужно сделать?
EXECUTE stmt USING in_Nom_tec, in_UID, in_date;

Comment: @razear Код откорректировал. Проверяйте.

Comment: PS. В коде не проверяется корректность передаваемого имени таблицы. Если туда попадёт "кривой" символ (точка с запятой, одинарная кавычка, пр., или просто таблица не существует) - будет плохо. Так что по-хорошему следует предварительно проверить, что имя валидно (что таблица существует - через INFORMATION_SCHEMA), и только в этом случае выполнять запрос.

Comment: Ошибка при принятии запроса :
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1336: Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: @razear Значит, преобразуйте в процедуру. Куда деваться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91538/discussion-between-razear-and-akina).